# Is it true that $(A + \epsilon B)^{-1} \cdot \epsilon v = \epsilon A^{-1}v + o(\epsilon)$ as $\epsilon \to 0$?

Tags: calculus, matrices, asymptotics

I am reading [this ML paper on Influence Functions](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.04730) and have a problem understanding Appendix A, equation (13). Omitting all irrelevant context from the paper, imagine that we have a function

$$f(\epsilon) = (A + \epsilon B)^{-1} \cdot \epsilon v$$

where all encountered matrices are nice and invertible, $v$ is some vector.
Authors claim in the equation 13, that as $\epsilon \to 0$ we got:

$$f(\epsilon) = \epsilon Av + o(\epsilon)$$

In other words, we can discard $\epsilon B$ as being $O(\epsilon^2)$. But how is it so? By using the identity $\frac{1}{\lambda} M^{-1} = (\lambda M)^{-1}$, we can see, that:

$$
f(\epsilon) = (A + \epsilon B)^{-1} \cdot \epsilon v = (\frac{1}{\epsilon} A + B)^{-1} \cdot v
$$

So there is no $\epsilon$ term in front of the matrix $B$ whatsoever! How can we discard it as being $o(\epsilon)$?

Comment: You have a typo in the second displayed equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(A+\epsilon B)^{-1} = \big(A(I+\epsilon A^{-1}B)\big)^{-1}= (I+\epsilon A^{-1}B)^{-1}A^{-1}=\big(I-\epsilon A^{-1}B + O(\epsilon^2)\big)A^{-1}$. Now multiply by $\epsilon v$.